# Escaping special characters of an xpath in sed

Tags: bash, xpath, sed

I have been trying to use sed to input a value, which includes multiple special characters. A sample value is `//*[@id='login_username']`

if we would use this value without any escape character, the command would look like this:

```
sed -i 's/Text to be replaced/new text and some xpath like //*[@id='login_username']/' target.txt
```

I tried escaping each special character with a `\` char, which resulted in following structure: `//\*\[@id='login_username'\]`

Also tried surrounding the value with double quotes but that doesn't work either. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different separator in the `s///` command instead of `/`, for example `s|||`:

```
sed -i "s|Text to be replaced|new text and some xpath like //*[@id='login_username']|" target.txt
```

In the replacement text, the only things you need to escape are:

- `"` because it's used to enclose the `sed` parameter
- `|` because it's used as the separator in the `s///` command

You can escape these with `\`, for example `\"` and `\|`.